# What are the storage requirements for running a node?

Tags: storage

What are the current and projected future storage space requirements for running a Tezos mainnet node?

As I understand, garbage collection and zk-snarks could reduce the storage required in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of today(2/18/2019), the chain size is `~95GB`. The chain grows about `.5GB` per day so if we don't change anything, namely [garbage collection](https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html), we'll need about `100GB` upgrade about every 7 months.

But since [garbage collection](https://blog.nomadic-labs.com/introducing-snapshots-and-history-modes-for-the-tezos-node.html) will be implemented soon, there will be choices of 3 separate modes: `archive`, `full` and `rolling`. These are their descriptions:

> `full` nodes store all chain data since the beginning of the chain, but
>   drop the archived contexts below the current checkpoint. In other
>   words, you can still query any block or operation at any point in the
>   chain, but you cannot query the balances or staking rights too far in
>   the past.
>
> `rolling` nodes are currently the most lightweight, only
>   keeping a minimal rolling fragment of the chain and deleting
>   everything before this fragment (blocks, operations and archived
>   contexts).
>
> `archive` nodes store everything. This corresponds to the
>   current behaviour of Tezos nodes.

Essentially, your storage requirements will differ based on what mode you choose to run based on your individual needs. If you choose to run an `archive` mode, nothing will change and the chain will grow at the rate of what's currently on the `mainnet` branch. If you run at the new default mode `full`, [according to Arthur](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/90/101), the storage will be at least 10 times smaller. But if you choose to run at `rolling`, your storage requirement will be much smaller as you don't store any of the context data.

To give you some perspective, given the `95GB` total size now. The breakdown between real chain and context storage is `6GB` and `85GB` respectively. If these modes were used now, `rolling` mode would presumably be around `6GB` and `full` would be about `15GB` (`6GB` + `85GB * .10 or 8.5GB`).

---

Note:
You can get the size of chain and context from the following files:

`~/.tezos-node/store/data.mdb`

`~/.tezos-node/context/data.mdb`

Answer (score 2):

My dedicated miner/machine has 8gb of ram and a 512 gb SSD. SSD could be less, but data is increasing about 0.5gb per day and I wanted enough space to not have to worry.

Comment: Can you please precise how much space context is taking for you ?