# What are checkpoints?

Tags: shell

The online documentation describes an error "Block incompatible with the current checkpoint."

What is a checkpoint, and when can this error be thrown?

Comment: You can have a look at this until someone answers in more details https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/486/118